# search and replace string in java using pattern

Tags: java, regex

Given the string

```
Content ID [9283745997] Content ID [9283005997] There can be text in between Content ID [9283745953] Content ID [9283741197] Content ID [928374500] There can be valid text here which should not be removed.
```

I want to remove the text starting `Content ID` followed by `[9283745997]` any numbers can be present between square brackets. Eventually I want the result string to be

```
There can be text in between There can be valid text here which should not be removed.
```

Could anyone please provide a valid regex to capture this recurring text but the numerals within square brackets are unique?

I appreciate your help!

My soulution to this was :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(Content ID \\[\\d*\\] )");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while(m.find()) {
  m.appendReplacement(sb, "");
}
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb);
```

Comment: Your approach seems to be working fine. Can you describe what problem you are facing?

Comment: I posted the problem initially and found the solution and thought of adding the working solution here. This site did not allow to answer my own question hence I have edited the question to include the solution I came up with. Thanks all for replying.

Answer (score 2):

So basically you are trying to remove each of `Content ID [one or more digits]`.
To do this you can use `replaceAll("regex","replacement")` method of String class. As replacement you can use empty String `""`.
Only problem that stays is what regex should you use.

- to match `Content ID` just write it normally as `"Content ID "`
- to match `[` or `]` you will have to add `\` before each of them because they are regex metacharacters and you need to escape them (in Java you will need to write `\` as `"\\"`)
- to represent one digit (character from range `0-9`) regex uses `\d` (again in Java you will need to write `\` as `"\\"` which will result in `"\\d"`)
- to say "one or more of previously described element" just add `+` after definition of such element. For example if you want to match one or more letters `a` you can write it as `a+`.

Now you should be able to create correct regex. If you will have some questions feel free to ask them in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the regex

```
Content ID \[\d+\] ?
```

Implement it like this:

```
str.replaceAll("Content ID \\[\\d+\\] ?", "");
```

You can find an explanation and demonstration here: http://regex101.com/r/qD5rJ6

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer

Comment: @ANTO If one of the answers completely solves your problem, you should accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
(Content ID \[[0-9]+\])
```

You can test it here: http://regexpal.com/

Comment: regexpal is very useful to try out instantly. Thanks